# Cannot deploy Windows 10 UWP App to Device

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, uwp, windows-10-mobile

So I'm trying to start Windows Mobile 10 development. Every single time I try to deploy my app to my phone, I get the following error:

DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147023436

Which seems to be at timeout error. I've taken a number of steps to combat it, but nothing seems to work. Here's what I have/have done:

- Windows 10 version 1511 (10586.420) deployed to a VMWare Player VM.
- Lumia 640 (AT&T Go Phone, not activated with AT&T as I just want to develop with it), upgraded to Version 1607 (10.0.14385.0) using the Windows Insider app (fast ring). I tried the slow ring and preview versions as well, same error each time. I should note that the default Upgrade OS option wouldn't upgrade to Windows 10 for me even though I've read that AT&T has pushed the update out for 640's. I have no idea why, but maybe that's important.
- 14383 SDK installed on VM (I cannot seem to find 14385 SDK available to download?)
- IP over USB service is running
- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3 14.0.25421.03
- Phone is visible to VM. I can open it in Windows Explorer and manipulate files on it.
- Phone is in Developer mode. USB connections to local network is on. Device Portal is on.

I really have no idea what could be wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: [This seems to be MS issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9304af75-a544-4c08-9334-f807610878d1/cannot-deploy-uwp-app-to-win10m-14356-dep0001-unexpected-error-2147014836?forum=wpdevelop), I've also experienced it three weeks ago, when I wanted to try it with Redstone - I had to revert to 10586 build. I hoped that VS update 3 change something, but looking at your post seems like I have saved few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that it may have been the fact that I was running in a VM. I tried running the VM on two other machines, nothing worked. Finally found a computer with Windows 10 on it and tried running my solution directly, and voila, it works.

So I guess Visual Studio is currently incapable of deploying stuff to a phone if it's running in a VM? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Romasz is correct. I have the same issue on my 640 xl because i am on fast ring. my 950 works fine because it is on release.

When i rolled back my 640 xl to release, all started to work fine again.